# How to use local URLs after HTML BASE tag

Tags: html, css, url, include, radix

After the following tag:

`<base href="http://mycompany.com/">`

How can I e.g. include local stylesheets (*local: in the same directory as the HTML file*):

```
<script src="[what to write here?]standard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST** the src/href attributes are resolved at run time by it self. You only need to specify the relative address..
**SECOND** If you want to use `<base>` tag.. All you need to do is to specify `<base href="" target="">`
Now all the src/href attribute you specify will be referred as relative address based on `<base>` tag.
Further all the links, doesn't matter you specify target or not they get it from `<base>` tag
[**For example**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_base_test)

Comment: thanks, now I can understand whats going on, but it won't work in my case :), the html file is in a file on my computer and the base refers to the corporate website :P

Comment: @gen you probably don't need to use Base at all if that's the case, just make sure the resources (.js/.css) are stored locally too. If that doesn't clear things up for you,

Comment: @redditor Yeah, maybe, but maybe not :), anyway, you made me understand the situation, and that's what matters

Comment: @gen `<base>` tag might be helpful if you want your each `<a>` tag to open in **new tab or window**

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea, although you cannot do this in HTML. I first thought of a PHP workaround, but how about this Javascript idea: (clears the base tag when required)

```
function BaseWorkaround(elementId) {
    var baseTag = document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0];
    var existingBaseHref = baseTag.href;
    baseTag.href = "";
    location.href = elementId;
    baseTag.href = existingBaseHref;
  }
```

Then on your href you could do something like

```
 ="BaseWorkaround('your_url_goes_here')">
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that, you are including javascript, not stylesheet.
Secondly, you don't need to write anything, just name of file (.css/.js) will do the job.
i.e

`<script src="standard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: I am quite sure it wont work after the <base> tag... -.- it's the most obvious solution, which, of course, doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

it's `<script src="standard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` if it's in the same map.
So nothing before there